# How to use halfling glyphicons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Visiting glyphicon.com -halflings tab, there's an icon that I want so much. It's the "group" (forth from the last row). I have used other icon using:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gbp"></span>
```

but this icon has different classes, what it means? I read that halflings icon are free for bootstrap users on w3c web site.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp

Comment: You're going to have to buy _Glyphicons All_ package to get that icon. It is not a part of the set that is included with Bootstrap.

Comment: Only 260 icons from the halflings are given to bootstrap for free. This is not one of them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use fontawesome instead, there is a nice looking group icon:

http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icon/group/

Here is the link to get you started with fontawesome:

http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

> Disclaimer: I know I should not reply with links because the pages
>   could be removed, but in this case I found it appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very similar icon for free on Elusive. Try http://fontello.com/ or http://elusiveicons.com/icon/group/.

Answer (score -1):

It means that the CSS attributes defined for the two referenced classes ("glyphicon" and "glyphicon-gbp") are both being applied to the HTML element that references those classes.

If both classes have different settings for the same CSS attribute, the setting of the last class referenced should have precedence.